# Optimize eigen expression

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to optimize the code of this multiplication:

```
A += s * (C + (D-U) * (D-U).transpose());
```

where `s` is a scalar, `C` is a matrix (usually 10x10), `D` and `U` are vectors. I tried with:

```
A.noalias() += s * (C + (D-U) * (D-U).transpose());
```

but I think it's not enough reading [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicWritingEfficientProductExpression.html). What's the best way to optimize this expression in eigen?

Comment: Start by evaluating `D-U` into a temporary vector so that it's evaluated only once, and then, since your vectors are tiny, try replacing `*` by `.lazyProduct(...)`, and more importantly bench accurately your changes with full compiler optimizations ON.

Comment: @ggael that should be the answer - you wrote in a comment

Comment: Are `A` and `C` self-adjoint?

Comment: They are covariance matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by evaluating `D-U` into a temporary vector so that it's evaluated only once, and then, since your vectors are tiny, try replacing `*` by `.lazyProduct(...)`. More precisely, you would end up with:

```
auto DU = (D-U).eval();
A.noalias() += s * (C + DU.lazyProduct(DU.transpose()));
```

Of course, you must bench accurately each change with full compiler optimizations ON to see if they are really effective and not counter productive.

Finally, if `A` and `C` are symmetric you might be tempted to update only one half of A. This would make sense for large matrices (e.g., >200x200), but since your matrices are pretty small this would be counter productive because of logic overhead and less effective SIMD.